# What is the cause of and how can I prevent mold on an interior wall close to my bed?

Tags: mold

Our main bed is pushed against the corner in our room. There's a very small amount of space between the mattress and the two walls. We removed the frame and the headboard so that the box spring sits on the floor.  We did this so that it is easy and safe for our kids...so they can climb in an out easily.

My wife and I both sleep so that our head is on the wall side. We've noticed that black mold would eventually appear on the wall on the side of the mattress where our head is.
(I clean it up with bleach and alternate with vinegar)

However, the other side of the bed that is against the wall, does not have this mold problem.

(Note: both walls that our mattress is touching are exterior facing walls and they do not have insulation, we live in Southern California, we live a block from the beach)

What could be the cause?  What is the best way to prevent this?

Comment: It is because you are a block from the beach.

Comment: Did you have this problem before? If not it's a not likely but there could be some problem with your mattress. If not your problem is most likely condensation.

Comment: It only happens on one side of the mattress that is adjacent to the wall.  The other side of the mattress that is adjacent to the wall does not have this problem.  If it were proximity to the beach then I think that I would expect that all of my walls would have this issue. (I did think about the humidity due to proximity to the beach, but what I observe doesn't seem to support that)

Comment: my only thought is that you have condensation caused by the slight heat coming from your heads, breath, bodies something that is insulated by blankets on the other sides. a headboard would help in this regard, or you could have a fan to circulate air in the room.

Comment: No I meant since you are living a block from the beach in paradise you needed to be given a few small problems...  If the wall has mold, you have to replace the drywall or it will keep coming back.  If you think it is just surface, clean it up then put a piece of plastic over it with taped edges.  That will tell you if your problem is inside or outside.

Comment: Mold is caused by condensation. Condensation is caused by high humidity and/or low temperature (of the surface on which you have mold). What is the temperature and humidity of the room?

Comment: Humidity of the room is 50 - 60%.